# AWS link databases and run query on multiple databases

Tags: postgresql, amazon-s3, linked-server, multiple-databases

We have multiple postgreSQL databases hosted in AWS RDS and I was wondering if it's possible to join them together and run queries on multiple databases like this for example:

```
SELECT * FROM databaseA.TableX ax
LEFT JOIN databaseB.TableX bx ON bx.id = ax.id
```

I remember that SQL Server has this feature and it's called linked server.

Comment: It's called `foreign data wrapper` in Postgres

Comment: Thank you for the info.
I followed the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/postgres-fdw.html) until the user mapping part. Now how do I select records from the foreign tables?

Comment: I found the solution, after the user mapping:
`CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT exists northwind;
IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA "public" FROM SERVER foreign_server INTO "northwind";
SELECT * FROM "northwind"."categories";`

Answer (score 0):

This is the complete sequence of commands:

```sql
-- Install extension
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgres_fdw WITH SCHEMA "public";

-- Link the foreign server
CREATE SERVER foreign_server
    FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw
    OPTIONS (host '<url>', port '5432', dbname '<database>');

-- Map the local user with the foreign one
CREATE USER MAPPING FOR <local user>
    SERVER foreign_server
    OPTIONS (user '<foreign user>', password '<foreign user password>');

-- Create locally a schema
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS "northwind";

-- Import the foreign schema into the new local one
IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA "public" FROM SERVER foreign_server INTO "northwind";

-- Select from foreign table
SELECT * FROM "northwind"."categories";
```